# Rsync error on Vagrant File

Tags: bash, vagrant, ansible, rsync

I want to deploy an application using Vagrant. The structure is:

```
- Vagrant box;
- frontend;
```

I want to read .ts files outside vagrant box.

My vagrant file:

```
 ...
      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vbox, override|
        vbox.cpus       = 2
        vbox.memory     = 4096
        override.vm.box = 'box/centos-7.2'
        config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
        override.vm.synced_folder '../frontend/', '/frontend', type: "rsync", rsync__exclude: get_ignored_files()
      end

 config.vm.provision 'ansible_local' do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook      = 'ansible/ionic_configuration.yml'
  end
      ...

    def get_ignored_files()
      ignore_file   = ".rsyncignore"
      ignore_array  = []

      if File.exists? ignore_file and File.readable? ignore_file
        File.read(ignore_file).each_line do |line|
          ignore_array << line.chomp
        end
      end

      return ignore_array
    end
```

My .rsyncignore:

```
.DS_Store
.idea
.git
.vscode
```

ERROR:

Running ansible-playbook....
bash: line 2: cd: /vagrant: No such file or directory

What I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Running ansible-playbook.... bash: line 2: cd: /vagrant: No such file
>   or directory

and

> ```
>     config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
> ```

are incompatible.

If your provision needs to access `/vagrant` directory, do not disabled the shared folder. Just remove the line

If you do not want to leave the `/vagrant` default shared folder, you need to change your provision so it does not access this folder and use another shared folder.